# Google charts piechart Material design

Tags: gchart

I need to show data in several types of charts and I like the look and feel of the Material design charts over the default google charts. 
Linecharts and barcharts work nicely, however, a piechart does not seem to be available in Material design... Or at least.. I can't get it to work.

On this page, Google states that for every corechart, a Material design is available:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

> Creating Material bar charts In 2014, Google announced guidelines
>   intended to support a common look and feel across its properties and
>   apps (such as Android apps) that run on Google platforms. We call this
>   effort Material Design. We'll be providing "Material" versions of all
>   our core charts; you're welcome to use them if you like how they look.
>
> Creating a Material Bar Chart is similar to creating what we'll now
>   call a "Classic" Bar Chart. You load the Google Visualization API
>   (although with the 'bar' package instead of the 'corechart' package),
>   define your datatable, and then create an object (but of class
>   google.charts.Bar instead of google.visualization.BarChart).

On the piechart page, Material design is not mentioned at all:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

I have tried to draw the table as explained above, loading 'pie' instead of 'corechart' and loading  'google.charts.Pie' instead of 'google.visualization.PieChart'. This does not work.

Has anyone got a google piechart to work in Material design? Or is it really not available?

Answer (score 3):

Add options theme in function drawChart()

```
  var options = {
     theme: 'material'
  };
```